# Between Debian and Ubuntu 18.04, which is the less bloated to create a server?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

I want to create a small server on Azure (1 VCPU and 1 GB of RAM) for testing and I was wondering which is the less bloated between Debian and Ubuntu

Comment: You might want to simply go with the distro you prefer and are most comfortable working with. "Bloat" is usually the least concern as you can always remove the unneeded "bloat" once the system is set up and running. Both distros, however, have very similar base system requirements.

Comment: Obviously Ubuntu is way more bloated than Debian in general for desktop use.  Ubuntu server and the Debian minimal.iso should be more or less equivalent for servers though.  But why Ubuntu ... it brings in so much more instability for server use cases than Debian would.  Bloat is a non issue, it's more about stability.

Comment: @oemb1905 I wouldn't call bloat a non issue. I can have a big impact when you are running multiple VMs and/or spinning them up frequently. There's a reason people use Alpine for containers for example.

Comment: I said bloat was a non issue when comparing Ubuntu server to Debian, not Ubuntu desktop.  Alpine is a minimalist OS, entirely different set of concerns. This post asked for a comparison of two specified OSs - alpine was not one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum recommended system configurations for [the current release of Debian](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch03s04.en.html) and [the current Ubuntu LTS release](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation) are as follows:

|  | Debian | Ubuntu |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CPU | 1 GHz (Pentium 4) | 1 GHz (model unspecified) |
| RAM | 512 MiB | 1 GiB |
| Storage | 2 GiB | 2.5 GiB |

This suggests that, by default, Debian will require fewer resources than Ubuntu.

Ultimately the requirements will be driven by what you do with your system, and will probably end up being similar regardless of the distribution you use (assuming no desktop environment).